# How to call the Users most recent selection in swift re: UIPickerView

Tags: swift

I am looking to store an integer a user selects from a scroll wheel

however once the user presses the button, myVariable is currently a sum of all the users selections they made when they moved the wheel up and down

How can I trigger the most recent selection via a button press?
eg:

```
// add most recent pickerView selection to totalData var
var totalData = 0
var tempData = 0

@IBAction func addButton(sender: UIButton) {

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    // ToDo: RETURN MOST RECENT SELECTION (??)

        if component == 1 {
            // Update the label
            // Increase temp data variable by number in the row: Add to totalData once button is pressed
            tempData += row
        }
    }

    // If tempData has a number pass it to tempData2
    if let tempData2:Int = tempData {
        totalData += tempData2
        print(totalData)
    }
    tempData = 0
}
```

// Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all the values in an array and when you want to get the latest value just:

```
let arr = [1,3,6,7,2]
let latestValue = arr.last! // will give you 2
```

To get the selected item in the `pickerView` use:

```
func pickerView(pV: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    print(arr[row])

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that will come to good use soon. However my problem is not yet solved- every time the user changes the scroll wheel my variable sums up all of the scroll wheel stops. How do I only use the most recent selection?

Answer (score 0):

The `pickerView(pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent` will be called as the picker is scrolled. Every time it is called you need to replace the previous value with the new. At the moment you are using "+=", so you are accumulating all of the row numbers into tempData.

It's not clear what your tempData2 code is trying to achieve. tempData is not an Optional, and will always contain an integer. Therefore there is no point in using `if let`. The compiler should be warning you about this already. Once again though, your code is using "+=" rather than just "=", and it's not clear why.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your advice. Yes one item is all that is required. Can't seem to get it to work still

Comment: Why are you adding tempData2 to totalData, rather than just setting it?